# Is there an Android function similar to php include()

Tags: java, php, php-include

am a php coder who's relatively new to Android programming and I was just wondering....I have a few functions which recur in every activity. Normally in php, I would put all these recurring functions in a file `functions.php` and include in each php page as `include('functions.php ');`. Is it possible to achieve the same in Android programming? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a `Utils` Class and depends on your needs have 'method` or 'static method` to achieve what you want.

Comment: @TamilSelvan this is wrong suggestion, as `import` is not equivalent of `include` for reason I gave in my answer

Comment: You can create a general Activity let say `BaseActivity` and could extend your each activity with it rather than simple `Activity` class. You can include even call back method of Activity life cycle in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is an object oriented language and therefore you can't define a function (static or not) that doesn't belong to an object. What you can do, however, is to define a class of all static methods like this:

```
public class Utils {

    public static void function1() { ... }

    public static String function2() { ... }

    }
```

and then call them in other classes using the `Utils.function1();` notation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to achieve the same in Android programming?

Android or not it makes no relevancy here. You talk about Java now and equivalent of `include` is not here, mostly because you cannot have any function without wrapping it into class, something which is not mandatory in PHP (and which lets you use `include` the way you describe).

What you should do however, is move all your all shared methods into one class (named `Utils` for example, or whatever) and then simply use its methods when needed. Most likely you will want to make these methods `static`, so you can use it w/o instantiation (i.e. `Utils.myMethod();`.